# find commands seem not to work with file name range

Tags: find

```
> ls
    chr10_canu.fasta  chr11.fasta      chr2_canu.fasta  chr3.fasta       chr5_canu.fasta  chr6.fasta       chr8_canu.fasta  chr9.fasta
    chr10.fasta       chr1_canu.fasta  chr2.fasta       chr4_canu.fasta  chr5.fasta       chr7_canu.fasta  chr8.fasta       circoletto_pbs.sh
    chr11_canu.fasta  chr1.fasta       chr3_canu.fasta  chr4.fasta       chr6_canu.fasta  chr7.fasta       chr9_canu.fasta
> find . -name "chr{1..11}.fasta"
```

Why does the `find` command not find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use **`find`**'s `-regex` option to find the filenames with numeric suffix from `1` to `11`:

```
find . -type f -regex ".*/chr\([1-9]\|1[01]\)\.fasta"
```

---

> **`-regex`** *pattern*
>                 File name matches regular expression *pattern*.  This is a match on the whole path, not  a  search.

Answer (score 0):

`before{1..3}after` is a zsh brace expansion operator (now also supported by some other shells) which **when not quoted** expands to several arguments: `before1after`, `before2after`, `before3after` that are then passed to  the command.

As you're quoting it, the `{1..11}` is left asis, and `find`'s `-name` wildcard matching operator doesn't treat those `{1..11}` specially so it just looks for files named literally `chr{1..11}.fasta`.

Even if you left it unquoted, `find` would not know what to do with:

```
find . -name chr1.fasta chr2.fasta...
```

For it to be useful, it would have to be:

```
find . \( -name chr1.fast  -o -name chr2.fasta... \)
```

and you can't use the `{x..y}` operator to achieve that directly.

Here, in this case, you could do:

```
find . \( -name 'chr[1-9].fast -o -name 'chr1[01].fasta' \) ...
```

Or the regexp equivalent if your `find` implementation supports them.

Or you could use `zsh`'s advanced recursive globbing:

```
printf '%s\n' **/chr<1-11>.fasta
```

which would also match on `chr01.fasta` or `chr011.fasta`, give you a sorted list and skip hidden directories.

Answer (score -1):

Change the {} to [] and so:

```
find . -name '*chr[1-11].fasta'
```

Comment: It only shows `./chr1.fasta`

Comment: `[1-11]` doesn't mean a numeric range from 1 to 11, it means a character range from `1` to `1`, and then character `1` again

Comment: Then how to create a range of 1 to 10 numbers?